# Angular ng model requires 2 click when using ng true and ng false

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using checkbox with ng model and ng-true-value and ng-false-value.
It works fine but when its value comes 1 and it checked by default then it will take 2 clicks to change the value.

Is there any way to do it with first click

Code Example :

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="CreateUpdateCat.IsDiscussionAllowed=='1'" ng-model="CreateUpdateCat.IsDiscussionAllowed" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="2" >
```

Controller Code :

```
angular.forEach($scope.CategoryData,function(v,k){
                        if(v.id == id)
                        {
$scope.CreateUpdateCat = {IsDiscussionAllowed:v.IsDiscussionAllowed,Name:v.Name};
};
});
```

here is plunkr url : https://plnkr.co/edit/JApepZfvNrlqDj9vine0?p=preview
value is 1 by default but checkbox is not showing checked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use `ng-checked` or `ng-model` otherwise angular will get confused to do it. and it may be possible that you will get unpredicted results.

Do use only one directive `ng-checked` or `ng-model`

Comment: but if value is 1 then its not showing checked by default

Comment: Not able to understand can you  create a fiddle?

Comment: IsDiscussionAllowed has a number of string? May be setting the ng values as follows might work? `ng-true-value="'1'" ng-false-value="'2'"`

Answer (score 0):

ng-checked should not be used with ng-model other wise you will get unexpected bihavior,
ng-check docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked

either use

```
 <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel.value"
       ng-true-value="'YES'" ng-false-value="'NO'">
```

OR

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="checkboxModel.value"
       ng-true-value="'YES'" ng-false-value="'NO'">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your input like this

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="CreateUpdateCat.IsDiscussionAllowed" ng-true-value="'1'" ng-false-value="'2'">
```

On your plunker, de scope CreateUpdateCat values are strings.

Answer (score 0):

Some times angualrjs scope stays dirt, you may want to use this:

```
$timeout(function(){
  angular.forEach($scope.CategoryData,function(v,k){
   if(v.id == id){
      $scope.CreateUpdateCat = {IsDiscussionAllowed:v.IsDiscussionAllowed,Name:v.Name};
    };
  });
});
```

This way the model updates itself to the dom element's valeue